# How can I display the Google rich snippets when a view is on "Show: fields" and the panel enabled?

Tags: views, panels, 7

I am building a site using Drupal 7 and the [schema.org module](https://drupal.org/project/schemaorg) and the [microdata module](https://drupal.org/project/microdata).

The site is live on production server (and works good).

When checking a url from my site site on the [google rich snippets tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets), I can't see all the fields I want to appear in the snippets.

When using panels, views, microdata module and schema.org module -
the snippets does not work.
When I deactivated the microdata module, and disabled the specific panel on the page the snippets work!
 So, I decided to disabled the microdata module, and work only with the schema.org module.

With the the schema.org modules:

- When views is on "show: content" and the panel Enabled - snippets work!
- When views is on "show: fields" and the panel Disabled - snippets work!
- When views is on "show: fields" and the panel Enabled - snippets do NOT work!

  Can I use the *Rewrite* option on a view to add some code to fields and make it work?
  How can I display the Google rich snippets when a view is on *Show: fields* and the panel enabled?

Comment: Scroll down in that page and check if
`type: http://schema.org/recipe` is being extracted. That would be the first place to look.

Comment: @GokulNK Thanks for your comment. I updated my questions according to your comment.

Comment: I haven't spent a great deal of time trying to understand the problem, but it sounds quite similar to something I recognize, so I figure I'd comment. Panels redoes the way nodes are rendered. Some modules rely on "Do stuff X when a node is rendered". Since panels bypasses the normal rendering, these modules all break. Possibly this is the case here. I've posted a generic workaround in the issue queue some time ago, which basically silently renders a node normally and throws the result away. Ugly, but works. Better solutions depend on the exact module in question.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using views fields mode for populating the values. That might be the issue.

In your overall HTML check that an entry for `itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">` is present. In your current html I feel you wouldn't have this. If that is the case then change the mode in your views to `node` from `fields`.

Then recheck your HTML and you should find the entry. If you do find the entry then the reason is that your fields(in old view mode) are not enclosed within a `recipe` tag.

In the above case you can install [schema tokens module](https://drupal.org/project/schemaorg_tokens) and then in your fields view, hide all the fields and then add a Global text field within which you can use these tokens to get the desired output.

Comment: I am using panels and panel fields. All my site is built through content panes (views) and panels, panels fields.I don't think I can change the content pane from fields to node. 
Can I use the  schema tokens module with panels fields?

Comment: If your node is in the scope and you can use the node tokens, then you can use schema tokens as well.

Comment: I tried to use the schema.org tokens, but I think I did not understand correctly. I don't see it in the "placements pattern" on the field on views, and I have no idea what to write and where. I tried to write: "%node:field_schemaorg_image" but it just printed the characters. I tried adding this token in the panel, but it just printed the url for the photo.